# How to remove all text except those matching format in Notepadd++

Tags: regex, notepad++

The text looks like this:

Line 1. Text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text "https://www.website.com/text/number" text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text  text text text text text text

Line n. Text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text "https://www.website.com/text/number" text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text  text text text text text text

I want to get just "https://www.website.com/text/number"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^[^"\r\n]*"([^"]+).*$`
- Replace with: `$1`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *DO NOT CHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           : beginning of line
  [^"\r\n]* : 0 or more any character that is not double quote or linebreak
  "         : a double quote
  ([^"]+)   : group 1, 1 or more any character that is not double quote
  .*        : 0 or more any character
$           : end of line
```

**Replacement:**

```
$1      : content of group 1
```

**Result for given example:**

```
https://www.website.com/text/number
https://www.website.com/text/number
```

Comment: @NhânPhạm: Thank you, glad it helps.